# Android Bottom navigation for tablet or big screens

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Can anyone help me how to get these kinda bottom navigation style in big screen.

**Mobile style**

[image: Bottom navigation for big screen]
**Big Screen(tablet)**

[image: Bottom navigation for mobile screen]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new project in Android-Studio and select "Bottom Navigation Activity"
[image: Bottom Navigation Activity]

This will create a new Project with a MainActivity with the navigation you want.
If you don't want to create a new project you can also just "steal" the logic from the generated project.